# Visual Studio clickOnce deployment issue

Tags: visual-studio, deployment

When I try to install my application generated in Visual Studio 2012 C# I get an "Value does not fall within the expected range." error. I have tried to install it with several users but to no avail.

Following are the details:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.34209
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.34244 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.34209 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.34244 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : file:///D:/Installer/documentGenerator/docGeni.application

IDENTITIES
    Deployment Identity     : docGeni.application, Version=4.0.0.10, Culture=en-AU, PublicKeyToken=31f8b94b44056c11, processorArchitecture=x86

APPLICATION SUMMARY
    * Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of D:\Installer\documentGenerator\docGeni.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Value does not fall within the expected range.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [4/10/2015 9:18:43 AM] : Activation of D:\Installer\documentGenerator\docGeni.application has started.
    * [4/10/2015 9:18:43 AM] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [4/10/2015 9:18:43 AM] System.ArgumentException
        - Value does not fall within the expected range.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.NativeMethods.CorLaunchApplication(UInt32 hostType, String applicationFullName, Int32 manifestPathsCount, String[] manifestPaths, Int32 activationDataCount, String[] activationData, PROCESS_INFORMATION processInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ComponentStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
            at System.Deployment.Application.SubscriptionStore.ActivateApplication(DefinitionAppId appId, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.Activate(DefinitionAppId appId, AssemblyManifest appManifest, String activationParameter, Boolean useActivationParameter)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    * Transaction at [4/10/2015 9:18:43 AM]
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreOperationSetDeploymentMetadata
            - Status: Set
            - HRESULT: 0x0
        + System.Deployment.Internal.Isolation.StoreTransactionOperationType (27)
            - HRESULT: 0x0
```

What does error mean? Which value is not within range?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by creating a brand application in VS and copying all the files from the old application to the new app.

Now I can install the app once again :-)

As far as I am concerned the issue is resolved but I would still like to you know the error means.